# order statistic (random sample from U(0,1) )

Tags: self-study, random-variable, uniform-distribution, beta-distribution, order-statistics

for a random sample $X_1 , X_2 .... X_5$ , from  a Uniform (0,1) , isn't the distribution of median (say y) be given by 
$$
f(y)= \frac{y^2 (1-y)^2}{\beta (3,3)}\,,\qquad 0 < y < 1 
$$
this can be obtained by directly using the result for the rth order statistic
$$
f(x)=\frac{F(x)^{r-1} (1-F(x))^{n-r}f(x)}{\beta (r,n-r+1)}
$$
I need to prove that $p( y < 1/3 )= p (y >2/3)$,

I am not getting it true , is my result is correct ? Is there any other trick or property that can be used instead of integration ?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then please edit to show your attempt.

Comment: What does $p(y < 1/3)$ mean? Isn't symmetry your friend (and nothing more?)

Answer (score 3):

Your Beta(3,3) density being symmetric implies that, when $Y\sim \text{Beta}(3,3)$, then $(1-Y)\sim \text{Beta}(3,3)$. Thus
$$\mathbb{P}(Y<1/3)=\mathbb{P}(1-Y<1/3)=\mathbb{P}(Y>2/3)$$

Comment: Good but this is self study so we should just hint at first. wolfies hint suffices until the OP comes back with some other questions.

Comment: I know that is what bothers me about self study questions.  I have a recent discussion question about it (the self study tag) on CV meta. My current thinking is to wait for the OP and after that if he is still having problems I give an answer. If days go by with no response from the OP I might then give the answer also. This trick of yours is worth knowing.

Comment: @Xian thank you so much xian ,.,., and yes i agree with u that a lesser hint would still have been confusing one , so thanks for the answer