# Calculating the Standard Deviation of Estimates from a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, standard-deviation, uniform-distribution

I was looking at this question on **Sufficient Statistics and the Uniform Distribution**: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359183/why-should-we-care-about-sufficient-statistics

In this question, the following example is provided about the Uniform Distribution:

> For example: if you are trying to estimate θ in Unif(0,θ), you might
> consider three candidate estimators: (a) double the sample mean, (b)
> double the sample median, and (c) (n+1)/n times the maximum
> observation among n. All three are unbiased. Only (c) is sufficient
> and it has the smallest variance of the three. Indeed, (c) has the
> smallest possible variance among unbiased estimators.
>
> Specifically, when n=5 and θ=10, the standard deviations of these
> estimators are 1.69 for (c), compared with 2.58 for (a) and 3.78 for
> (b). So there is a considerable difference in the variability of these
> estimates.

**My Question** : Can someone please explain how the standard deviations of (a), (b) and (c) are calculated? Where do the numbers 1.69 2.58 and 3.78 come from?

I tried to work out the standard deviation for (c):

- Standard Form: y = a*x
- var(y)= (a^2) * var(x)

Using the estimator in (c):

- thetha = ((n+1)/n) * max(x)
- var(thetha) = ((n + 1)/n)^2 * var(max(x))

Since n = 5

- sd(thetha) = sqrt( (6/5)^2 * var(max(x))

But I don't know how to proceed further.

**Can someone please show me how the standard deviations of (a), (b) and (c) were calculated?**

Thanks!

Comment: Gave you some clues at the linked page.

Comment: For max [see](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333105/distribution-of-extreme-values-case-of-uniform), but note that max is biased downward, hence $(n+1)/n$ for unbiased estimator.

Comment: More generally, for order statistics (including median) perhaps [see](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255122/order-statistic-random-sample-from-u0-1)

Comment: Try with order statistics (the Wikipedia page is enough to solve this homework).